# An expression in rational numbers $x, y,$ and $z$: Why is it a square of a rational number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers, square-numbers

Let $\,x,y,z\in\mathbb Q\,$ satisfy $\,xy+yz+zx=1$.
Given this, I would like to prove that
$$\big(1+x^2\big)\big(1+y^2\big)\big(1+z^2\big)$$
is the square of a rational number $n$.
That is, you can write ... let's call that $E(x,y,z)$.
You may say that $E(x,y,z)=n^2$ with $n\in\mathbb Q$.

I tried to factor it out, it just got worse.
I tried to prove some sort of relationship, and I ended up where I started.

**The only thing that seems to work is to write two of them in terms of the other, but that also gets me nowhere.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+x^2+y^2+z^2+x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+x^2y^2z^2$$

$$=1+(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)+(xy+yz+zx)^2-2xyz(x+y+z)+x^2y^2z^2$$

$$=(x+y+z)^2-2xyz(x+y+z)+x^2y^2z^2$$

$$=(x+y+z-xyz)^2$$

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $1+x^2=xy+yz+zx+x^2=(x+y)(x+z)$.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the hint and for not telling me the whole solution. I got to use my brain a bit more. CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

If I do the obvious thing, and write
$$z=\frac{1-xy}{x+y}$$
I get
$$1+z^2=\frac{(x+y)^2+(1-xy)^2}{(x+y)^2}
=\frac{1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2}{(x+y)^2}
=\frac{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}{(x+y)^2}.$$
I think the rest is clear...